# How to show that $Inv:GL(\Bbb{R}^n)\to GL(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analysis, derivatives, vector-spaces

How can I show that $\text{Inv}:GL(\Bbb{R}^n)\to GL(\Bbb{R}^n)$ given by $$\text{Inv}(x)=x^{-1}$$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$?

I know its derivative is $\text{Inv}'(x)\cdot v = -x^{-1}vx^{-1}$. How can I analyse its higher order derivatives and infer $\text{Inv}\in \mathcal{C}^\infty$?

Comment: The derivative is in terms of $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions ($x^{-1}$), so, just apply induction on $n$ to prove $\mathcal{C}^n $ for all $n\in\mathbb N$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that:
$$\textrm{inv}(x)=\frac{1}{\det(x)}{}^\intercal\textrm{Cof}(x),$$
where $\textrm{Cof}(x)$ stands for the cofactor matrix:
$$\textrm{Cof}_{i,j}(x):=(-1)^{i+j}\left|\begin{pmatrix}x_{1,1}&\cdots&x_{1,j-1}&x_{1,j+1}&\cdots&x_{1,n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\x_{i-1,1}&\cdots&x_{i-1,j-1}&x_{i-1,j+1}&\cdots&x_{i-1,n}\\x_{i+1,1}&\cdots&x_{i+1,j-1}&x_{i+1,j+1}&\cdots&x_{i+1,n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\x_{n,1}&\cdots&x_{n,j-1}&x_{n,j+1}&\cdots&x_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}\right|$$
Therefore, $\textrm{inv}$ is a rational fraction of the coefficients.

Comment: $^\top$ is at a weird place :D

Comment: @user251257 This is actually a reasonably common convention.

Comment: @user251257 I use the convention that a letter at the right of an object is an exponentiation. :)

Comment: @Travis it is so common that you need to remind me of it ... yes I have seen that once or twice. I wouldn't call it common.